# After calling JSONDecoder, no apparent changes to object

Tags: json, swift, xcode

So I have a function that is called by viewDidLoad and it fetches a specific movie from a database and then I am trying to parse this JSON data into a struct that I created using JSONDecoder. However whenever I try to print(movie) nothing shows up in the console, I can't find any signs that show that the decoder is working. However when I used

```
 let str = String(decoding: data!, as: UTF8.self)
           print(str)
```

I was able to see all the data in String format, but I want it in the struct for ease of use. The API call worked correctly in postman, identical to this str method above. Below is some of the code.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        fetchMovie { [weak self] (movie) in
            self?.movie = movie
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                // update labels and stuff
                self?.movieTitle.text = movie.title
                print(movie)
            }
        }
    }
```

```
func fetchMovie(completionHandler: @escaping (Movie) -> Void) {
        let url = URL(string: "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/475557?api_key=" + credentials.tmdb_key + "&language=en-US")!
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) in
          if let error = error {
            print("Error with fetching movie: \(error)")
            return
          }

          guard let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse,
                (200...299).contains(httpResponse.statusCode) else {
            print("Error with the response, unexpected status code: \(response)")
            return
          }
            // let str = String(decoding: data!, as: UTF8.self)
           // print(str)

          if let data = data,
            let movie = try? JSONDecoder().decode(Movie.self, from: data) {
            print(movie.adult)
            completionHandler(movie)
          }
        })
        task.resume()
    }
```

```
struct Movie: Codable {
    var adult: Bool?
    var backdrop_path: String?
    var belongs_to_collection: String?
    var budget: Int?
    var genres: Genre?
    var homepage:  String?
    var id: Int?
    var imdb_id: String?
    var original_language: String?
    var original_title: String?
    var overview: String?
    var popularity: Double?
    var poster_path: String?
    var production_companies: ProductionCompany?
    var production_countries: ProductionCountry?
    var release_date: String?
    var revenue: Int?
    var runtime: Int?
    var spoken_languages: SpokenLanguage?
    var status: String?
    var tagline: String?
    var title: String?
    var video: Bool?
    var vote_average: Double?
    var vote_count: Int?
}

struct Genre: Codable {
    var id: Int?
    var name: String?
}

struct ProductionCompany: Codable {
    var id: Int?
    var logo_path: String?
    var name: String?
    var origin_country: String?
}

struct ProductionCountry: Codable {
    var iso_3166_1: String?
    var name: String?
}

struct SpokenLanguage: Codable {
    var iso_639_1: String?
    var name: String?
}
```

Comment: Don't ignore `Decoding` errors with `try?`. Print the `error`. It tells you exactly what's wrong and where. And it's bad practice to declare everything carelessly as optional.

Comment: Ah I see. My reasoning was that I never really know what the API will return since I didn't write it. Where would I print the errors? When I am calling the decode function?

Comment: Wrap the `JSONDecoder()` line in a `do - catch` block, remove the `?` from `try?` and in the `catch` scope `print(error)` (but **not** `error.localizedDescription`)

Comment: And if I do this, I should remove the ? notation from each of those variables within the struct? And Swift automatically knows what to do when I print error? It does not need me to create some error variable? I'm getting the warning that the catch block is never reached because the do portion does not throw any errors.

Comment: It's recommended to declare the properties non-optional as much as possible and to add a question mark only if you get a *...but found null* error. The Decoding errors are very descriptive. As I said replace `try?` with `try` to fix the warning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `Movie` model does not match the API. Because of the mismatch, decoding fails, so the the optional unwrapping fails and this block that calls the closure (`completionHandler`) is never entered:

```swift
if let data = data,
    let movie = try? JSONDecoder().decode(Movie.self, from: data) {
    print(movie.adult)
    completionHandler(movie)
}
```

Documentation is available for [the `/movie/{movie_id}` endpoint](https://developers.themoviedb.org/3/movies/get-movie-details).

The following changes are necessary to get decoding working.

```swift
struct Movie: Codable {
    var adult: Bool?
    var backdrop_path: String?
    var belongs_to_collection: String?
    var budget: Int?
    var genres: [Genre]   // <-- array
    var homepage:  String?
    var id: Int?
    var imdb_id: String?
    var original_language: String?
    var original_title: String?
    var overview: String?
    var popularity: Double?
    var poster_path: String?
    var production_companies: [ProductionCompany]  // <-- array
    var production_countries: [ProductionCountry]  // <-- array
    var release_date: String?
    var revenue: Int?
    var runtime: Int?
    var spoken_languages: [SpokenLanguage]   // <-- array
    var status: String?
    var tagline: String?
    var title: String?
    var video: Bool?
    var vote_average: Double?
    var vote_count: Int?
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I now see that in the documentation it specifies that those are arrays.